# One page bootstrap dropdown not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used BS framework to build onepage website and
Used jquery's for:

**1.** scroll page on button click

**2.** dropdown on mouseover (if window width more than 992px)

*Page scrolling & mouse over functions are working fine.*

However, in mobile view, **when we have clicked on the dropdown button, menu get collapsed.**

See my code:

```js
//nav manu dropdown
if ($(window).width() > 992) {
  $(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
      });
  });
}
//end nav manu dropdown


//page scroll jquery
! function(a) {
  "use strict";
  a(document).on("click", "a.page-scroll", function(e) {
    var l = a(this);
    a("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollTop: a(l.attr("href")).offset().top - 0 //id top position
    }, 1250, "easeInOutExpo"), e.preventDefault()
  }), a("body").scrollspy({
    target: ".navbar-fixed-top",
    offset: 51
  }), a(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function() {
    a(".navbar-toggle:visible").click()
  }), a("#mainNav").affix({
    offset: {
      top: 100
    }
  }), window.sr = ScrollReveal(), sr.reveal(".sr-icons", {
    duration: 600,
    scale: .3,
    distance: "0px"
  }, 200), sr.reveal(".sr-button", {
    duration: 1e3,
    delay: 200
  }), sr.reveal(".sr-contact", {
    duration: 600,
    scale: .3,
    distance: "0px"
  }, 300), a(".popup-gallery").magnificPopup({
    delegate: "a",
    type: "image",
    tLoading: "Loading image #%curr%...",
    mainClass: "mfp-img-mobile",
    gallery: {
      enabled: !0,
      navigateByImgClick: !0,
      preload: [0, 1]
    },
    image: {
      tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.'
    }
  })
}(jQuery);
//end page scroll jquery
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#home">Logo</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service" class="page-scroll">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Coaches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Franchising</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Visit Our Store</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 If have dropdown-->
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="top-margin"></div>
<div style="height:800px; width:100%; display:inline-block; background:#eee; padding-top:100px;" id="home">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>


<div style="height:800px; width:100%; display:inline-block; background:red;" id="service">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Also added jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kduy9vp/

Any answers will be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu was collapsing on dropdown click, because you've asked it to collapse every time a list item is clicked, here:
`a(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function() {...`
 so we basically have to add an exception for your dropdown, like this:
`a(".navbar-collapse ul li:not(.dropdown) a").click(function() {...`

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2kduy9vp/22/

This way the list item containing the class *dropdown* won't collapse the entire menu on click.

Also for some reason the *hover function* wasn't working on my side, so I edited it a little... in case on yours it is working fine you can ignore it.

Cheers.